# cannot send long path filename (UNC path) to printer

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, printing, unc, paths

i'm using long path names with UNC (UNI), for example:

```
 \\?\c:\tmp......\file1.prn
```

but when i try to send the file to a printer on windows command-line, for example with copy/print command, it shows :
for copy -

```
0 file(s) copied.
```

for print -

```
invalid switch
```

the regular path / shortened (using ~) works well, its only the UNC large (>260 chars) that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for your case, but sometimes I have gotten over limitations of long UNC paths by mapping them to network drives and then using them as if they were local drives.

Im sure there’s a cleaner way, but unless the operation requires drives to really be drives and folders to be local folders, this trick might work as well.